# $3^{2x+1} \cdot 5^{x-1} = 27^x \cdot 5^{2x}$

Tags: logarithms

If
$$3^{2x+1} \cdot 5^{x-1} = 27^x \cdot 5^{2x},$$
how can I find the values of $15^x$ and $x$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to take log base 10 on both sides to get $\log{3^{2x+1}} + \log{5^{x-1}} = \log{3^{3x}} + \log{5^{2x}}$. No sure how to proceed.

Comment: @SifarJirgale you should include your attempts in the body of the question.

Comment: Oh ok thanks I will make sure to do that when I ask the next question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before taking logarithms, it would be preferable to try to group factors with the same base.  Since $27 = 3^3$, we have
$$1 = \frac{27^x 5^{2x}}{3^{2x+1} 5^{x-1}} = 3^{3x - (2x+1)} 5^{2x - (x-1)} = 3^{x-1} 5^{x+1}.$$

Another way you could write this is
$$\frac{3}{5} = 3^x 5^x.$$

Now how would you use this to solve for $x$?

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.